# Creating Web App & Want to be Sys Admin for myself - Help!

Tags: linux

I am in the process of creating a web app, and I have decided to work with open-source technologies: LAMP stack + Ruby.

I want to be able to manage my server myself, but I know there is much to learn. E.g. the major differences between the major linux distros, need to be familiar with the command line, bash scripting, etc.

I love Chris Pine's book on Ruby, and was wondering what sites do you guys know of have some good video tutorials, good articles and good books (both printed and eBook) should I look at to get started?

I am fairly technical, have a computer science first degree. I just learned how to program, learned the basics of reg. expressions at the command line (grep), and stuff like that but that was 3 or 4 years ago. Haven't touched it much since. So would like a good refresher that is easy to read and tailored to people that are 'n00bs'.

Thanks much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *really* want to be a sysadmin (and not just play one on the Internet) get a copy of "The Practice of System and Network Administration" by Limoncelli, et al.  Also, learn to find and absorb existing resources first -- this "how to become a sysadmin"/"resources to learn systems administration" question has popped up before on Server Fault.

Answer (score 1):

Basically get access to a linux box, virtual machine, chroot VM, anything basically. Asking how you learn to run a server is like asking how you learn to run a country -- you can't, you have to learn from experience. So go and get your hands dirty, and come back when you've got into a situation you can't fix!